# TLP175A High Load alternative

Tags: integrated-circuit

I came across this IC and it is an IC i need, but i would like to controll a heavier AC load with it, 220V 1A but this particular device is for low volatage levels. Is there high load alternative for this IC or a tool that will help me search through the alternatives in future

Comment: Watch this EEVBlog video to learn how professionals find the components they need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqlAq266aTs  Also, a TLP175 isn't really an IC, it is a photorelay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there [...] a tool that will help me search through the alternatives in future

You can use distributor's sites to search for such optocoupler/solid state relay:

Search for TLP175A on e.g. mouser.com, find which product group it is in.

> All Products  Opto-electronics > Optocouplers/Photocouplers > **MOSFET Output Optocouplers** > Toshiba TLP175A(TPL,E)

Click on **MOSFET Output Optocouplers** and use the filters to narrow down the result.
(and you'll find Mouser doesn't have it)